# How to add View Product Detail Link Beside "Add To Cart" Button In WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

I try to adding a function to display view product detail button beside add to cart . but not working please help me !

```
  add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'add_a_custom_button', 5 );
function add_a_custom_button() {
    global $product;
    if( $product->is_type('variable') || $product->is_type('grouped') ) return;
    echo '<div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
        <a class="button custom-button" href="' . esc_attr( $product->get_permalink() ) . '">' . __('VIEW PRODUCT') . '</a>
    </div>';
}
```

[HERE IS IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEIum.jpg)

Comment: This code is working for me. What is the error ? The rendering of the button added depends on your theme.

Comment: The button display in below add to cart button but not beside add to cart button ! here is image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEIum.jpg

Comment: Which theme are you using ?

Comment: Flatsome bro ! i want to display like here : https://imgur.com/a/Ymsp7nh

Comment: I know how you feel. It can be your theme issue. Is it free version or premium ?

Comment: premium version bro ! not theme issue ! issue from this function bro ! please help me fix thanks

Comment: I am using storefront theme and this code works fine. Could you please check if the hook `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item` is overridden in your flatsome theme ?

Comment: this code works fine but button not beside add to cart button bro :(

Comment: This code adds a button exactly at the position for me in storefront theme.